# Coin Flip Statistics Program - undefined method

Tags: ruby, instance-methods, singleton-methods

I'm trying to write a coin flip program where I can analyze the percentage of Heads flipped.  I've gotten coin flip to work, just not the actually analyzing yet.

The problem is when I created a Coin class in order to further break down the object into something like Coin.length afterwards.

Why am I getting an `"undefined method 'flip' for Coin:Class (NoMethodError)"   from flip.rb:14:in 'times'
    from flip.rb:14:in <main>`
 when I indeed have one?

```
class Coin

def flip
  flip = 1 + rand(2)
    if flip == 2 
        then puts "Heads"
    else
        puts "Tails"
    end
end 

end

10.times do
  Coin.flip
end
```

Here's a die roll example that I am somewhat trying to emulate:

```
 class Die

     def roll
       1 + rand(6)
     end

  end

    #  Let's make a couple of dice...
    dice = [Die.new, Die.new]

    #  ...and roll them.
    dice.each do |die|
      puts die.roll
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coin.flip is not a method you defined; this would be a class method, and to define a class method called `flip` you would write:

```
class Coin
  def self.flip
    ...
  end
end
```

What you created is an *instance* method, and as such it requires that it is called on an instance:

```
coin = Coin.new
coin.flip
# or
Coin.new.flip
```

In your second example (with the Dice), you are correctly calling `new` and creating instances.

Answer (score 2):

you defined instance method `filp`, but there is no class method called `Coin.flip`.